# Views templates deleted when core updated

Tags: views, updating

Yesterday, I posted a [proposal](https://www.drupal.org/node/2485057) for clarifying the procedure for updating core. But now I find that I messed up in doing my update and I'm not sure how to do it right the next time.

I have a set of Views templates under the Bartik theme. They are in the folder:

`<Drupal root>\themes\bartik\templates\views`

In the update procedure, this folder is deleted along with the rest of the old core.

I was able to easily restore the views folder from the backup, but I'd like to not have to do that in the future.

Generally, it seems like a bad idea to put custom content in a core folder, but it seems that Views needs the template folder to be under the theme it applies to.

Is there a way to put that views folder under the sites folder or somewhere else outside of the core structure so it won't get deleted when I do an update?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Editing files in themes\bartik\templates\views is hacking core. One ought not to. You should [create a subtheme](https://www.drupal.org/node/225125) of Bartik and make  your changes there. Then an upgrade will not wipe out your changes.

Clear exceptions to the rule for editing core files are robots.txt, .htaccess and web.config.

Comment: That folder was created by me as a subfolder of the core "bartik/templates" folder in order to keep my Views templates separate from the core files. As far as I understand, Views requires me to keep templates in the folder of the theme it is working with. I'm not making any changes to Bartik, so it seems excessive to create a whole subtheme just to be able to use Views with a theme. Am I wrong about any of that?

Comment: You need to create complete subtheme at `sites/[all|default|sitename]/themes/[subtheme_name]`. 

The minimum requirement for a theme is the `.info` file, so you will likely start with that and your template file, which I would put in `themes/[subtheme_name]/templates/views/*`

Adding a few directories and one additional file isn't a big deal.

Comment: @NewSites follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Cfc11_sb5M

Comment: @fullerja - I've done some more research and found out that you're right that I should be using a subtheme. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually quite some information available about updating – at least over at drupal.org.

[Here is the page *'Update Drupal Core'*](https://www.drupal.org/node/1494290) in the Community Documentation at drupal.org and [here](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install/modules-themes) is a neighbouring page about *'Installing modules and themes'* that may clear some aspects of how and where to put modules and themes etc. But you probably came across these pages.

However – in short: first thing I learnt is to **always** put your custom themes, modules etc. in `sites/all/…` or `sites/default/…` since that's a folder that is not deleted – or at least should not be deleted while updating core.

[EDIT] Sometimes you may encounter problems finding the correct name for your tpl file – then drupal won't load it and you'll have the impression that *'it just does'nt worl'*. Views has astally a handy feature listing the suggested tpl names for a specific view – it's just a bit hidden: `Advanced > Theme: Information`.

For further info on naming these pages could also be useful: '[Views template files](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/group/views_templates/7)' and '[Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656)'.

ps: rule of thumb: **don't touch the core!** 
(That's why it's called *'core'*  -- and this applies also to *'core modules'* )

Comment: The update page you link to is included in my proposal (linked in my question) for changes to the updating instructions. As far as I understand, Views requires me to keep templates in the folder of the theme it is working with. I was not able to get Views to recognize templates put anywhere else. So unless you're telling me not to use Views with Bartik, it seems that I have no choice but to put Views templates in Bartik's folder. Am I wrong about that? (At least I keep them in a separate subfolder to distinguish my templates from Drupal's.)

Comment: afaik **all** template files can go into `sites/all` no matter if it's a views template or any other. There may be however a naming problem? What is the name of the view / name of the template file…?

Comment: I tried putting my first template within "sites" and Views didn't find it. Researching the problem, I found a post that said the templates have to be in the folder of the theme being used. So I put it there and that's when Views found it. Have you used Views with a core theme and put the templates under "sites"? If you did, please say what path you used and I'll try it. For your other question, I have three views under Bartik. One of the templates is "views-view-table--z-links-gen--block-1.tpl.php". These names are generated by Views and I have no control of them.

Comment: I've submitted an issue (https://www.drupal.org/node/2486123) to Views about this. It is excessive to require a subtheme just to be able to use a module. Views is requiring a violation of Drupal best practices in order to use it with a core theme.